# Duvida sobre como colocar duas coisas diferentes na mesma view

Tags: c#

Galera, tenho um pequeno sistema que cadastra equipamentos e softwares. 
Na modelagem de dados um equipamento pode ter vários softwares instalados nele, com isso na primeira vez fiz um `crud` para cadastrar somente os equipamentos e depois um `crud` para cadastrar todos os softwares daquele equipamento.

Bom como os senhores notaram, fiz isso em `crud` separados.

Eu gostaria de fazer tudo isso em um único `crud` que seria o do equipamentos, vi em um tutorial de como fazer isso, só que tive alguns problemas no meio do caminho.

Estou utilizando o ADO.NET e EntityFramework.

Peço desculpas pelo tamanho da pergunta, mas eu quis postar todo o código!
Meu código esta assim:

Model Equipamento:

```
public partial class tblEquipamento
    {
        public tblEquipamento()
        {
            this.tblEquipamentoSoftware = new HashSet<tblEquipamentoSoftware>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int equIdEquipamento { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o NIP do Equipamento")]
        [Display(Name = "NIP")]
        public string equNip { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<tblEquipamentoSoftware> tblEquipamentoSoftware { get; set; }
    }
```

Model EquipamentoSoftware:

```
public partial class tblEquipamentoSoftware
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        [Display(Name = "NIP")]
        public int eqsIdEquipamento { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        [Display(Name = "Software")]
        public int eqsIdSoftware { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o Tipo")]
        [Display(Name = "Tipo")]
        public string eqsTipo { get; set; }

        public virtual tblEquipamento tblEquipamento { get; set; }
        public virtual tblSoftware tblSoftware { get; set; }
    }
```

Model sofware:

```
 public partial class tblSoftware
    {
        public tblSoftware()
        {
            this.tblEquipamentoSoftware = new HashSet<tblEquipamentoSoftware>();
        }

        public int sofIdSoftware { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o software")]
        [Display(Name = "Nome")]
        public string sofNome { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<tblEquipamentoSoftware> tblEquipamentoSoftware { get; set; }
```

Controller Equipamento:

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
           //Eu Adicionei essa parte aqui do ViewBag pq me basei em um tutorial, mas se estiver errado peço que me avisem pfvr
            ViewBag.eqsIdSoftware = new SelectList(db.tblSoftware, "sofIdSoftware", "sofNome");
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "equIdEquipamento,equNip, tblEquipamentoSoftware")] tblEquipamento tblEquipamento)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.tblEquipamento.Add(tblEquipamento);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.eqsIdSoftware = new SelectList(db.tblSoftware, "sofIdSoftware", "sofNome", tblEquipamento.tblEquipamentoSoftware);
            return View(tblEquipamento);
        }
        public ActionResult NovoSoftwareEquipamento()
        {
            tblEquipamento equ = new tblEquipamento();
            return PartialView("_SoftwareEquipamento", new tblEquipamentoSoftware { eqsIdEquipamento = equ.equIdEquipamento});
        }
```

Bom eu criei duas _PartialView para poder adicionar a parte do `EquipamentoSoftware` no crud do `Equipamento`

View Equipamento:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>tblEquipamento</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.equNip, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.equNip, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.equNip, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

            @Html.Partial("_Softwares")

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" class="btn btn-success" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Agr a Partial que criei:

_Softwares:

```
@model IEnumerable<TesteCadastroAtivo.Models.tblEquipamentoSoftware>

<div class="actions">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="adicionar-novo-software">
        Adicionar Software
    </button>
</div>

<div id="area-software">
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        foreach (var software in Model)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_SoftwareEquipamento", software);
        }
    }
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#adicionar-novo-software").click(function () {
            $.get('/Equipamento/NovoSoftwareEquipamento', function (template) {
                $("#area-software").append(template);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

_SoftwareEquipamento:

```
@model TesteCadastroAtivo.Models.tblEquipamentoSoftware

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("tblEquipamentoSoftware"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.eqsIdEquipamento)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.eqsIdSoftware)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eqsTipo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eqsTipo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eqsTipo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1">
            <a class="btn red" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove();">Excluir</a>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Gente se eu deixar o código até aqui consigo fazer aparecer na tela de Equipamento para o usuário colocar o tipo do software, porém eu quero colocar também para o usuário selecionar o Software, só que quando coloco essa parte no meu `_SoftwareEquipamento` ele da um erro

```
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eqsIdSoftware, "eqsIdSoftware", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("eqsIdSoftware", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eqsIdSoftware, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Erro gerado:

> Additional information: The ViewData item that has the key
>   'eqsIdSoftware' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type
>   'IEnumerable'.

Alguém poderia me ajudar, desculpa qualquer coisa, estou aprendendo ainda!!!

Comment: Tal como o erro indica, está a usar usar uma key para ir buscar um elemento e usa o elemento como se fosse IEnumerable, mas ele é um System.Int32 no seu model.

Comment: E como eu posso fazer para deixar o usuário selecionar o software?]

Comment: eqsIdSoftware é a chave da tabela de software certo?

Comment: @MauroAlmeida sim, certo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fonte do exemplo](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/asp-net-mvc-populating-dropdown-lists-in-razor-views-using-the-mvvm-design-pattern-entity-framework-and-ajax)

**CustomerDisplayViewModel.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace BlipDrop.ViewModels
{
    public class CustomerEditViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Customer Number")]
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Customer Name")]
        [StringLength(75)]
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Country")]
        public string SelectedCountryIso3 { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "State / Region")]
        public string SelectedRegionCode { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Regions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Create.cshtml, Country snippet**

```
...
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.SelectedCountryIso3, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-5">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.SelectedCountryIso3, new SelectList(Model.Countries, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "Country"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedCountryIso3, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
...
```

**CountriesRepository.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace BlipDrop.Data
{
    public class CountriesRepository
    {
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCountries()
        {
            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                List<SelectListItem> countries = context.Countries.AsNoTracking()
                    .OrderBy(n => n.CountryNameEnglish)
                        .Select(n =>
                        new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Value = n.Iso3.ToString(),
                            Text = n.CountryNameEnglish
                        }).ToList();
                var countrytip = new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Value = null,
                    Text = "--- select country ---"
                };
                countries.Insert(0, countrytip);
                return new SelectList(countries, "Value", "Text");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

É só seguir o exemplo e mudar para o seu objetivo.
Este exemplo mostra uma lista de países em uma DrowpDownList.

Comment: @Rafael, se achou que a resposta o ajudou a resolver o seu problema coloque como resposta aceite.